# Securing url pattern based on user properties Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have secured certain url patterns for my project based on the users role as seen in my spring_security xml below.

```
 <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" access-denied-page="/auth/denied.do" >

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/auth/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/security/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_SECURITY')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/common/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/notsecure/**" access="permitAll"/>

    <security:form-login
        login-page="/auth/login.do"
        authentication-failure-url="/auth/login.do?error=true"
        default-target-url="/common/tasks/tasks.do"
        authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"/>

    <security:logout
        invalidate-session="true"
        logout-success-url="/auth/login.do"
        logout-url="/auth/logout.do"/>

</security:http>
<sec:global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />

<!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="authenticationService">
        <!--   <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/> -->
    </security:authentication-provider> 
</security:authentication-manager>

<!-- Use a Md5 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as Md5 in the database -->
<!--
<bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder" id="passwordEncoder"/>
-->

<!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access levels  -->
<bean id="authenticationService" class="ie.premiumpower.services.AuthenticationService"/>
<bean id="mySuccessHandler" class="ie.premiumpower.services.MySuccessHandler">
</bean>
```

So only admin users can access /admin/** etc.

Now I want to limit users to their own url pattern based on a different attribute (their site_id which is just an int). So only users with a site_id of 1 can go to the url "/1/**" and so on.

How can I go about doing this? Just looking for a point in the right direction. Everything I've seen so far doesn't allow me to have a variable url-pattern. As in "/{variable}/".

Comment: You can check in JSP by using spring-security taglibs as to which roles the logged in user has. Based upon that, you can decide whether to show the URL... If they don't see the URL, they don't go there. If they try by some hijacking/hacking, then it wont work as Spring-security or your config will stop them. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No I am already able to limit URL's based on the role. This is working perfectly.

I now want to limit based on a different attribute of User.

Comment: And what if I change the URL in browser to : givemeadminstuff/2/*.. Then what will you do?

Comment: All the admin pages are accessed using "/admin/**". These can't be accessed by anyone who does not have the role "admin". This works perfectly. Someone without the role "admin" cannot access any pages with "/admin/". 


I now want to do something different. I want to make it so that if a user wants to access the url "/limitaccess/1/", they must have a site_id of 1. And if they want to access "/limitaccess/2/" they must have site_id of 2. So everytime the url "/limitaccess/x/*" is attempted I want to check if x == the site_id of the logged in user.

Comment: To clarify what I want to do has nothing to do with the users role, or whether they are an admin or not. This has been done already.

Comment: Where are you getting these numbers from? Why are they so relevant and what is happening behind the curtains of this limitaccess/1/* . I cannot understand the reason of this overhead, that's my question? Explain me why rather then what.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96233/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-onetwo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html

See "15.3 Method Security Expressions"

You can use something like

```
@PreAuthorize("#value == '123'")
@RequestMapping(value="/secure")
@ResponseBody
public String aloa(@RequestParam("value") String value, Principal principal) {
        return "Hello " + principal.getName();
}
```

This will only let you in if you provide "value=123" as a request Parameter.

You may also use @PathVariable here:

```
@PreAuthorize("#value == '123'")
@RequestMapping(value="/secure/{value}/data")
@ResponseBody
public String aloa(@PathVariable("value") String value, Principal principal)
```

If you want fine-grain access control to your domain objects, you may want to use spring-acl for such purpose. There you can define fine grained access control for any object base on user permissions. Heres the simple base on which acl is base uppon, too. you can throw in your own implementation of PermissionEvaluator and then make use of "hasPermission" inside the @PreAuthorize:

Link it in in your security config:

```
<global-method-security secured-annotations="disabled" pre-post-annotations="enabled">
        <expression-handler ref="expressionHandler"/>
    </global-method-security>

    <beans:bean id="expressionHandler" class="org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler">
        <beans:property name="permissionEvaluator" ref="myPermissionEvaluator"/>
    </beans:bean>
```

create a "hasPermission" PreAuthorize constraint:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#value, 'admin')")
@RequestMapping(value="/secure/{value}/data")
@ResponseBody
public String aloa(@PathVariable("value") String value, Principal principal)
```

Fill a PermissionEvaluator with life. Here you can bridge your domain-permission over to spring-security: The referenced value from your @RequestMapping will come in through the "targetDomainObject" in "permission" you'll find the required permission as defined in your "hasPermission" definition above.

```
@Component("myPermissionEvaluator")
public class MyPermissionEvaluator implements PermissionEvaluator {

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission) {
                return ...;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Serializable targetId, String targetType,
            Object permission) {
        return ...;
    }

}
```

you may even directly access the Principal object from within the annotations, too:

@PreAuthorize("#value == authentication.principal.title") //my pricipal is from ldap source and title is mapped in from there.